# How to convert Date string to java Date?

Tags: java

Im having difficulty converting the following date string `"2014-07-10T11:31:35"` to a java Date object in android.

so `Date date = new Date("2014-07-10T11:31:35");` returns null, which causes a null reference exception

```
public class DateUtil {

    public static String FromIsoString(String datestring)
    {
        String formattedDateString = "";
        try {
            if (!datestring.isEmpty()) {

                Date date = new Date(date string);//-->>>> returns null 
                String format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
                formattedDateString = FromIsoString(date, format, locale);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e(ex.getLocalizedMessage(),"FromUtcString");
        }
        return formattedDateString;
    }


    public static  String FromIsoString(Date date, String format, Locale locale){
        String dateString = null;
        try
        {

            dateString = new SimpleDateFormat(format, locale).format(date);

        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e(ex.getLocalizedMessage(),"FromString");
        }
        return dateString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give the specific error you are receiving. See this guide on [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It would help if you'd post the right code. This code uses a dd/MM/yyyy format, and doesn't even compile. Also, don't use the String constructor for dates, it's deprecated.

Comment: its right there in the code, it returns null, which causes a null reference exception.

Comment: Xerxes, That is really obscure. Put it in the text surrounding as well.

Comment: Then how do you expect `2014-07-10T11:31:35` to match dd/MM/yyyy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ISO8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/**
 * Format date with specified Date format
 * @param dateString
 * @param inFormat format of input date
 * @param outFormat format of result date
 * @return dateString
 */
public static String formatDate(String dateString, String inFormat, String outFormat){
    DateFormat inFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(inFormat);
    inFormatter.setLenient(false);
    DateFormat outFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(outFormat);

    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = inFormatter.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }

    return outFormatter.format(date);
}
```

and call it like `formatDate("2014-07-10T11:31:35"", inFormat, outFormat)`

where `inFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"` and `outFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"`